# Copy Certain substrings from one column to another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of text of many rows. For instance:

"Saturday morning was nice"
"Yesterday was Friday"
"He went to the store at night"

How can I extract certain keywords, say the days of the week ("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", etc.) from every row and store it in a new column. I'd rather not loop. Maybe use a lambda function?

Answer (score 2):

No need lambda , here is `findall`

```
#l=['Monday',...'Sunday'] define you own list
df['Newcol']=df.Date.str.findall('|'.join(l))
0    [Saturday]
1      [Friday]
2            []
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Get the following error: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: @user10939484 try look at whether your df is one of the subset from orthers , if so adding .copy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for this:

```
words = ['Saturday', 'Friday']
df['Word'] = df['Strings'].str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(words)))

print(df)

                         Strings      Word
0      Saturday morning was nice  Saturday
1           Yesterday was Friday    Friday
2  He went to the store at night       NaN
```